# PIP Install Failing

Tags: python, django, firebird, pip

I am learning Python and the documentation I am following suggested installing Firebird. I ran `sudo pip install fdb`.

I saw a build directory which I understand just contains the source code and not the binaries so I deleted that. When I do `pip freeze | grep fdb`, I cannot find Firebird.

I tried running `sudo pip install fdb` again and I am getting this error now (and the build directory is returning):

```
Downloading/unpacking fdb
  Downloading fdb-0.9.9.tar.gz (481Kb): 481Kb downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package fdb
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 14, in <module>
      File "/Users/nayef/Documents/Django/build/fdb/setup.py", line 7, in <module>
        from fdb import __version__
      File "fdb/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
        from fdb.fbcore import *
      File "fdb/fbcore.py", line 26, in <module>
        from . import ibase
      File "fdb/ibase.py", line 1164, in <module>
        isc_attach_database = fb_library.isc_attach_database
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 366, in __getattr__
        func = self.__getitem__(name)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 371, in __getitem__
        func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
    AttributeError: dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, isc_attach_database): symbol not found
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 14, in <module>

  File "/Users/nayef/Documents/Django/build/fdb/setup.py", line 7, in <module>

    from fdb import __version__

  File "fdb/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>

    from fdb.fbcore import *

  File "fdb/fbcore.py", line 26, in <module>

    from . import ibase

  File "fdb/ibase.py", line 1164, in <module>

    isc_attach_database = fb_library.isc_attach_database

  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 366, in __getattr__

    func = self.__getitem__(name)

  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 371, in __getitem__

    func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))

AttributeError: dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, isc_attach_database): symbol not found

----------------------------------------
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /Users/nayef/Documents/Django/build/fdb
Storing complete log in /Users/nayef/Library/Logs/pip.log
```

What am I doing wrong here? I'm not sure what's wrong with pip. I never faced any issues with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't *pip* failing, this is the *fdb* package installation failing.

It seems you have some drivers missing, specifically, the firebird header files.

Do you have [firebird installed](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/papers_presentations/html/paper-fb-macosx-install.html)? Make sure you install the Python bindings only after the driver has been installed.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that pip only installs the Python bindings only.